# Why is it better to enqueue Google Fonts in Functions.php vs style.css in a WordPress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I'm having trouble finding an answer to why it's better to enqueue Google fonts in the functions.php file vs adding `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,800,900');` directly to the style sheet.

I read on one site that if you use the style sheet method the CSS file loads twice?  That's bogus, right?  Why is the functions method superior?

Answer (score 4):

Enqueuing the style sheet in your functions.php is better just in case there might be another plugin that wants to use the same font. If it's properly enqueued using the `wp_register_style()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` functions then WP will only include the link once, no matter how many plugins want it. However, `@import` it yourself (or add the link manually to your header.php) and WP can't know about those, so it will get loaded more than once.

Of course, if you know exactly what resources your theme and plugins are using, and know that nothing else will want to load the same font, it doesn't really matter if you link to or import it manually!

Comment: I'm using Genesis and they use this.  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sp_load_google_fonts' );
function sp_load_google_fonts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'google-font-Raleway', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,800,900', array(), CHILD_THEME_VERSION );
}

Comment: With the GDPR upon us, using the functions.php gets another plus: a plugin can easily hook into it and load the fonts from a local copy instead of having the client send a (potentially tracking) request to Google.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a large and strong developer community. Thousands of people all around the world design themes and plugins for WordPress. To ensure that everything works properly and that one plugin or theme doesn’t break another, WordPress has an enqueue script function. This particular function provides a systematic way of loading Javascript along with styles.

With the help of the `wp_enqueue_script()` function, you can easily inform WordPress the best time to load a script long with dependencies if any. Such a feature allows everybody to utilize the built-in Javascript libraries that come in a bundled form. It also helps in reducing the load time of page along with avoiding easy conflicts with themes and plug-ins.

Enqueuing scripts in WordPress also ensures that duplicates with the same handle are not loaded twice.